# php => desktop informer (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, alert

I need to find Desktop Information Soft...

For example: web-store, after receiving an order => the program must alert manager...

Ideal is... program need to periodically requests an php-script for new orders, and if it was => inform a manager

**UPD.** I'm finding something like "reach inform application", **with** server side developing... Much (as it may be) customizable...

Comment: so... whats the question in here?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (i.e. a way that does not require client side programming) might be setting up an [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) in PHP.

There are dozens, if not hundreds RSS feed readers out there for every conceivable platform; I'm pretty sure you'll find one that matches the requirements. If I remember correctly, Windows Vista and/or 7 have a built-in sidebar widget to display RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You may use built-in Windows scheduler and some script (PHP), which would connect to your server, check whether new orders arrived, and exec() notepad with opened information about order :)

Another way is, send e-mail notifications about every new order.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Adobe AIR to develop a simple JS based desktop software which polls your server every X seconds to see if there is an update.